# How do I use np.linspace() to change the pixels colors of a patch in an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I drew a straight line by changing the color of 50 pixels in the image below. The line is the diagonal line shown on the image

[image]

Here is how I did it.

```
zeros = torch.zeros_like(img) #img is b,c,h,w

x1, y1, x2, y2, r, g,  b = 16, 50, 100, 100, 6, 2, 4
rgb = torch.tensor([r, g, b])
cx, cy = x2 - x1, y2 - y1

for t in np.linspace(0, 1, 50):
    px, py = x1 + t * cx, y1 + t * cy
    zeros[0, :, int(py), int(px)] = rgb

mask = (zeros == 0).float()
im = mask * img + (1 - mask) *zeros
```

It is obvious in `np.linspace(0, 1, 50)` that I am changing 50 pixels. I want to use **the same method** to change a specific portion of the image, like a `14 x 14` patch of my image if the image size is `224 x 224` or even more. The range of pixels to cover now will be 196 -> (since there are 196 pixels in a `14 x 14` patch) instead of 50. How do I go about it, please?

Comment: do you use PIL ?

Comment: I actually loaded the image with PIL and converted it into tensor. My aim is to use exact or similar approach that I have used to draw a line in the image above. Not with any inbuilt function

Comment: you could use nested loop to access each pixel in the image (14x14) then change its value according to your need .

Comment: Is it a must to use `np.linspace`? Why can't you perform slicing?

Comment: I have actually done slicing but I am still far away from what I want.`x1`,`y1`,`x2`, `y2` above are the starting and ending points of the line while `r` `g`  `b`  are the color values.With this,I can efficiently choose where the line starts and ends and assign some values to the color channels. What I want is similar to this, choose `x` , `y` location of the image (say a`14 x 14` patch) and then change their `rgb` values. So a patch here would be `[x, y, r, g,b]`.I assume doing this would assign only 1 `rgb` values to all pixels within the patch & `np.linespace` can help have different values

Comment: An example is, if I have a `32 x 32` image size and I divide into a `4 x 4` patch each, I will have `64` patches in total with `8 x 8` dimensions. so if I want to change the pixels of the patch at row 3 and column 6, all I have to do is  `x, y, r, g, b = 3, 6, r-value, g-value, b-value`. I have done this with masking but I want a more efficient way like I have described

Comment: What do you mean by "(since there are 196 pixels in a 14 x 14 patch)"?

Comment: @Prefect, there are `1024` pixels in  a `32 x 32` image size. Assume you select `14 x 14` portion (patch) of this image, you would be selecting `196` pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `img` dimensions are BCHW based on the comment in the first line.
You can change values pixel by pixel in a for loop (which is quite inefficient):

```
img[0, :, y, x] = rgb
```

Or you can change the whole patch. Assuming `img` is Numpy `ndarray` and you want to reduce intensity:

```
img[0, :, 100:200, 100:200] = (img[0, :, 100:200, 100:200] / 1.3).astype(np.uint8)
```

Just put attention to dimensions and data types. You have to convert the result to `uint8`, same as original image.

To set some intensity gradient on the patch:

```
gradient = np.tile(np.linspace(0.2, 0.9, 100), (3, 100, 1))
img[0, :, 100:200, 100:200] = (img[0, :, 100:200, 100:200] * gradient).astype(np.uint8)
```

Here `0.2-0.9` is intensity and `100` is the patch size. So `gradient` is 3x100x100 tensor. I create it by taking a vector of intensities of shape (100,) and tiling it so it becomes a 3x100x100 tensor. The last line is a multiplication of each value in `img` by corresponding value in `gradient`.

---

When working with images it is much more convenient to represent them in HWC format. You can easily achieve that by writing

```
img = img[0].transpose(1,2,0)
```

This will swap dimensions CHW->HWC (as Batch is removed by indexing [0] ). Then you can easily write:

```
img[y:y+patch_h, x:x+patch_w] = rgb
```

and Python will automatically will try to fit missing dimension. In this case a 3-d vector `rgb` will be [broadcasted](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to `patch_h`x`patch_w`x`3` tensor. Same logic works for Python native `arrays`, NumPy `ndarray`, Pytorch and TF tensors. Then you can (for example) flip a patch by

```
img[y:y+patch_h, x:x+patch_w] = np.fliplr(img[y:y+patch_h, x:x+patch_w])
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution. The last code snippet and the one before it produces a similar result to what I want. I can leverage it for further manipulation.